# responsive design screens wider than 960px

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm creating a responsive website based on this article
[link](http://www.cheesetoast.co.uk/responsive-web-design-3-column-layout/)

but I added this code for screens more than 980 px width

```
 /* for more than 980px */
@media screen and (min-width: 981px)

{
#pagewrap {
width: 94%; 
}

#content {
width: 20%;
}

#middle {
width: 50%;
}

#sidebar {
width: 20%;
}

}
```

you can see the result in codepen
[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKyAi)

when I set width of #middle 50% or 49%
and resize browser width to somthing near 990px
3rd Content Area goes at the bottom of two other area
but when set width to 48% its ok, I mean now 3 area are next to each other

but now another problem arises.
when browser size is something near 1395 px (my laptop)
theres a 53px Gap between 3rd Content Area and wrapper border like below (I dont want that gap)
[image]

any suggestion?

Comment: Check this http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/#relative

Comment: Seems like your 50px gap is due to the 94% width of #pagewrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're running into are box-model issues. You see, you have widths set, but also margins and paddings and borders that are all messing with the actual, *calculated* width of your boxes. Worse, even, those margins/paddings/borders are defined in pixels while your widths you've done so in percentages.

To achieve what you want, you should use a `border-box` box model.

```
#content, #middle, #sidebar {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Now, when you say `width:50%;` that means "make my boxes' width 50%, *including any padding and borders*" (note, not margins).

Using `border-box` to layout your columns should help you immensely, but it will require you to change the calculations.